# Django pypdftk - subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python-3.x, django, pdftk

I'm tring to fill a pdf with information from a dictionary. When i run the following code:

```
fields = {'zeitraum': getMonth(month), 'arzt': doc.name, 'rechnungsnr': verrechnungsNr, 'verrechnungsbasis': total['verrechnungsbasis'],               'marketing': total['marketing'], 'dauer': str(total['dauer'])+" min.", 'miete': total['miete'], 'geraeteaufwand': total['geraet'],               'labor': total['labor'], 'material': total['material'], 'materialust': materialust, 'mwst':mwst, 'gesamt': gesamt}          
result = pypdftk.fill_form('/assets/docs/sf_rechnung_arzt.pdf', fields)          
return FileResponse(result, as_attachment=True, filename='output.pdf')
```

i get the following error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pdftk /assets/docs/sf_rechnung_arzt.pdf fill_form C:\Users\pataki\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpyf2o6cgc output C:\Users\pataki\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\2\tmpqqolt1_3 flatten' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

And I can't figure out what's wrong. Does anyone have hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well most probably bcs the pdftk commandline tool is not installed. ‍♂️